# CakePHP 2 not handling binary fields properly

Tags: cakephp, pdo, binary-data

I'm having real problems with CakePHP 2.x (2.1.5, 2.2.7) inserting binary data into the database.

My problem is that when I insert raw binary data into the database, I get the following error:

> Error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters

My insert code looks like this:

```
        $imageData = array(
            $this->alias => array(
                'parent_id' => $imageId,
                'image' => $imageBlob,
                'encoding' => $encoding,
                'mime_type' => $mime_type,
                'file_name' => $options['fileDetails']['name'],
                'width' => $imageWidth,
                'height' => $imageHeight,
                'size_type' => $resizeName,
                'owner_class' => $options['ownerClass'],
                'token' => $this->generateToken()
            )
        );

        $this->create();
        $this->save($imageData);
```

If I base64 encode the imageBlob data before the insert, then the insert works fine.  Similar code in CakePHP 1.3 worked fine, without having to base64 encode the data first.  The column in MySQL is a MEDIUMBLOB.

I've started tracing the code through the cake libraries, and have determined that the column type is correctly being guessed as 'binary', and execution is running the 'binary' case:

```
        switch ($column) {
        case 'binary':
            return $this->_connection->quote($data, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
```

I'm also quite surprised that Cake doesn't actually use the normal PDO syntax with named parameters, it just builds up a big long SQL string.

Could my problems with inserting binary data be because I'm running in PHP 5.2.6 or MySQL 5.0.45?  (Both quite old versions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this is a limitation with the PDO system in PHP 5.2.6.  See this bug for more information: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44251

Apparently this is fixed in PHP 5.2.8, which is why CakePHP's requirements say that 5.2.8 is the minimum version of PHP that is compatible with it.

So the resolution is to either Base64 your data, or upgrade to PHP 5.2.8.

I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the exact same issue with PHP 5.2.6 and MySQL 5.0.45-7.  The issue is not happening 5.4.4 and MySQL 5.5.25 using the same code base and CakePHP 2.1.5.

When looking at the stack trace and SQL insert statement, my binary data does contain single quote characters, which I'm sure is the part of the query that is throwing the column name/value count off as it states in the error message.

The only solution I could come up with was to base64 encode the binary file data before inserting it into the database (and of course base64 decoding when serving it back out).  I will be interested to see if there is a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for posting, bergy.

I've just verified that this problem is still present in CakePHP 2.3.0 as well.  

I'd imagine that the most likely issue is to do with the PDO system in PHP 5.2.6, more specifically this bug:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44251

I guess we just have to upgrade to a later version of PHP.

Comment: Thanks Ben.  I think you're right in that updating PHP is the only way to circumvent having base64 the data before insertion.  Note that I would have just commented on your post, but my rep isn't high enough (will have to fix that at some point) and I wanted to make sure you knew you weren't the only one running in to this limitation.